# {aborted, {bad_type, {...} } on mnesia:write/3

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Supressing irrelevant code, i've the following:

```erlang
% somefile.erl

-record(task, {description, date, completed = false}).

init() ->
  {atomic, _} = mnesia:create_table(task, [{attributes, record_info(fields, task)}]).
```

In other file, where the `{aborted, {bad_type, {}}}` is ocurring:

```erlang
-record(task, {id, description, date, completed = false}).

create_task(Req, State) ->
    Task = create_task_record(),
    Transaction = fun() -> mnesia:write(task, Task, write) end,
    {atomic, _} = mnesia:transaction(Transaction),
    % ...
```

When i'm running the code, in the line `{atomic, _} = mnesia:transaction(Transaction)`, i'm receiving the error `{aborted, {bad_type, {task, ...}}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours trying to find, the problem here is in the record `task` definition. I wasn't using the `hrl` to share definitions, so i have the definition where i was using it, because of this, in one file the definition was missing the `id` attribute, so i was having  different types.